# Scope of THIS keyword in Function?

Tags: javascript, dom, function, mootools, this

Should 'this' in the following code not still refer to the DOM object selected by the MooTools selector?

```
$$('div').addEvent('click', function()
{
    var click1 = function(){$(this).setStyle('background', 'red');}
    click1();
});
```

Comment: What's up w/ all the JS frameworks always using $? There are better function names out there, no?

Comment: @Esteban: It's a very short name that won't conflict with anything else  (except other frameworks).  It's better than `s` (or similar names) because no-one will use it as a local variable name, and it's better than `findElements` because it's shorter.

Comment: @Esteban - You have a better variable name? :)

Comment: @SLaks and @Nick: I just think it's getting kinda silly, that's all.

Comment: @Estaban you'll be happy to hear that `$` in MooTools is deprecated in favor of `document.id()`

Comment: and $$ used to be an alias to `this.document.getElements`, also being deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do this instead to refer to the element you want:

```
click1.call(this);
```

Otherwise `this` refers to `window` inside the function, [you can see the working version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/7EArh/).

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?  The alternative answer provided is more expensive for this particular example, saying what's *wrong* with this answer might actually help others.

Comment: Sure, this will work but it's not the MooTools way of doing stuff. Chrys is using a JS framework for a reason.

Comment: well, if you are talking expensive, then perhaps the whole thing should be refactored. for example, if the function is not being re-used, there's no sense in saving it. using `$(this)` in mootools is redundant, this is not jquery - especially in the context of a callback from an event where the element would have been extended already. using `.bind` or `.pass` are chainable mootools methods that allow binding+passing of arguments. I would argue `expensive` in the context of an extra function call is not an issue (unless animating)--code legibility+best framework practices are more important.

Comment: @Dimitar - Using a more expensive route for something that can be done in vanilla JavaScript with the same amount of code is "best framework practices"...really?  Neither of you have explained what's *wrong* with the answer, and more importantly, the other answer *fails to answer the question*.  The author asked what `this` would be, as he has it, it would be `window` inside his `click1()` call, but the @Oskar's answer failed to mention that.  Sure it's a good practice to go that way for *most* things, but you start by answering the question...

Comment: well, clearly you know your mootools so I will just take your word for it.

Comment: @Dimitar - You seemed to have missed my point entirely, it's a *JavaScript closure question*, regardless of framework, as it's written, `this` won't maintain context in `call1`...regardless of which framework you're using...

Comment: no, i have not missed your point but you need to look at the bigger picture. the answer could have simply been `'this' will be window`. the reason why we are having this argument at all is that since mootools is class-centric development, people go out of their way in order to keep `this` referencing the class instance even in event callbacks and achieve it through the '.bind' wrap, amongst other ways. showing how to change scopes is far more useful, imo. anyway - no skin off my nose.

Answer (score 2):

You should do it the MooTools way - by binding `this` to the `click1` function - http://jsfiddle.net/oskar/7EArh/5/

```
$$('div').addEvent('click', function() {
    var click1 = function() {
        this.setStyle('background', 'red');
    }.bind(this);
    click1();
});​
```

Also `this` is already extended with MooTools methods, so there is no need for doing `$(this)`.

Comment: +1 and also, mootools way: `click1.run(args, this);` - > check http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:run and the other `Function` methods.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to handle it is this:

```
var click1 = function() {
    this.setStyle('background', 'red');
};

$$('div').addEvent('click', click1);
```

in the above, 'this' get's passed to the function called.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gT5dc/

Answer (score 0):

No.  `click1()` isn't associated with any object (it's not e.g. callable as `obj.click1()`), so in it `this` refers to the window.

However, you can do:

```
click1.call(this);
```

The [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method basically sets `this` to its first parameter.

Comment: To be clear it that should read it sets `this` to it's *first* parameter :)

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of crazy situation, I just do:

$$('blah').addEvent('click', function() {
    var self = this;

```
var click1 = function(){ self.setStyle(....); }
click1();
```

});

... of course. mostly none of my code would include a click1(); at the end. These kind of inner functions like click1 would normally be used for some other purpose. for e.g.

var click1 = function(){ self.addClass('blah2').removeClass('blah'); }
self.set('tween', { onComplete: click1 }).fade('in');